# how to make a jar file auto run after reboot or start of a system

Tags: java, linux, jar, centos

I have a jar file that tracks system info and logs it every 24 hours. How can I make it so that if the system restarts or starts the jar file is started as well? I am running a linux server with CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to add

`java -jar YourJarFile.jar`

in

`/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

Note: Commands in the above file are run at startup (as root). Note that if you do this, your command will NOT respond to the usual service start/ stop commands.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following link: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html
Basically, you should just run your jar from the /etc/rc.d/rc.local script

Answer (score 2):

In addition of other (valid) answers, you could consider adding a [crontab](http://linuxmoz.com/crontab-syntax-tutorial/) entry with `@reboot`.

<sup>The `@reboot` syntax to `crontab` is a "Vixie" extension, but that syntax is common on Linux.</sup>

This supposes that your Linux system has [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which is very likely. In addition, it does not require superuser privilege. You have to run the [crontab(1)](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_crontab.htm) command to set it up.

You may still want to have your java program a regular linux "service". See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8859338/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16140050/841108) answers.